# Core data NSAsynchronousFetchRequest errors: expected type after and before ->

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to delete Core-data entity records using NSManagedObject like this:

```
func deleteEntity<EntityType: NSManagedObject>(_: EntityType.Type) -> Bool? {
    var fetchedResults: [EntityType] = []
    
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
 
    let fetchRequest = EntityType.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<EntityType>
    
     let asyncFetch = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) throws -> Void { asynchronousFetchResult in
         guard let result = asynchronousFetchResult.finalResult as? [EntityType] else {
             return
         }
        if result.count > 0 {
            for aEntity in result {
                context.delete(aEntity)
                try context.save()
            }
        }
        NSLog("Deleted \(EntityType.self).")
    }
    return true
}
func testDelete() {
    if self.deleteEntity(Contact.self) == true {
        print("success")
    }
}
```

I get following errors in the line when I call NSAsynchronousFetchRequest

```
"Expected type after '->'"
"Expected type before '->'"
```

NSAsynchronousFetchRequest throws Void, but I still get error

If I change that line:

```
let asyncFetch = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, completionBlock: { (asynchronousFetchResult) -> Void in
```

then I get following error:

```
"Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(NSAsynchronousFetchResult<EntityType>) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(NSAsynchronousFetchResult<EntityType>) -> Void'"
```

How to fix this?
Also how to return if the operation fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your second attempt is the correct one, the first one is just bad syntax.

So it should be

```
let asyncFetch = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) { asynchronousFetchResult in
```

The error you then get is that you call a function that throws, `try context.save()`, but the completion block is not declared to throw and you are not handing the throw inside the block hence the error message

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(NSAsynchronousFetchResult) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(NSAsynchronousFetchResult) -> Void'

There are several ways to deal with this and one is to move the save to after loop and to catch the error

The whole function would then become

```
func deleteEntity<EntityType: NSManagedObject>(_: EntityType.Type, context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Bool? {
    let fetchRequest = EntityType.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<EntityType>

    let asyncFetch = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) { asynchronousFetchResult in
        guard let result = asynchronousFetchResult.finalResult else {
            return
        }

        for aEntity in result {
            context.delete(aEntity)
        }
        // Could also be written as: result.forEach(context.delete)

        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                //log error...
            }

        }
        NSLog("Deleted \(EntityType.self).")
    }

    return true
}
```

Of courser you could use a save and `do/catch` inside the loop if you want to continue the loop.

Comment: Not sure why your function is returning an optional boolean.